# Use Html.fromHtml with android 8 hex digit color resource

Tags: java, android, html, colors, textview

So, say I have some colors defined in my R.java file such as "public static int red=0x7f06000c;"

How do I apply the color in the html code?

I tried

```
Html.fromHtml("<font color= '" + R.color.red + "'> some text  </font>)
```

but the color returned is black...

Thanks for answering my question!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
Html.fromHtml("<font color=" + getResources().getColor(R.color.red) + "> some text  </font>");
```